# Inactive outlook add in becoming active in Outlook 2010

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-2010

We have an outlook add in with load behaviour defaulted as 9.

Initial loading of the add in is working. Now the user can go and make the add in inactive. In this case the load behaviour rightly becomes 8. In the current session of the outlook it remains so.

But once inactive and user starts outlook again, the add in becomes active and is loaded again. So the load behaviour becomes 9 again.

This problem is only observed in Outlook 2010 professional version. In outlook 2013 it is working fine.

Is there any way i can found out why it is happening or does anyone have any hints ?

cheers,

Saurav

Comment: Did you register the add-in for all users? Do you run Outlook as an administrator?

Comment: Also make sure that all the latest updates and service packs are installed for Outlook/Office 2010.

Comment: it is registered for all users with value as 16....my user has admin privileges when i run the outlook...i don't run outlook separately as admin...my Outlook 2010 is updated with all the service packs...

Answer (score 1):

When users try to disable add-ins (registered in the HKLM hive) in Office applications they get the LoadBehavior key created in the HKCU hive. Try to change LoadBehavior key value in the HKLM hive of windows registry instead and see the result.

Comment: thanks @eugene for your comments...you meant the "they get the LoadBehavior key created in the HKLM hive." instead of HKCU hive right ?...so you are saying to change the value in HKLM rather than in HKCU when user disables the addin ?...another question is this problem is only happening in Office 2010 not in 2013

Comment: Did you try to change the LoadBehavior value in the HKLM hive? Does it help?

Comment: also changing value in HKLM we don't want because this will change the settings for all the users ?...if one user has disabled it ...let it be his preference

Comment: Then you need to register the add-in on the per-user basis. I believe in that case users will be able to disable add-ins without issues.